# How to configure Jmeter to achieve desired throughput

Tags: jmeter

I have created a performance test script as below. I am running 4 Thread Groups in parallel (Even though there are 14 Thread Groups, only 4 are enabled and I am running only those enabled 4 Thread Groups). I have used default Thread Groups.

[image]
[image]

I have used Flow Control Action to simulate the user think time and set it as 3 seconds.

[image]

My requirement is to achieve Throughput as 6.6/seconds. What is the best way to achieve it? Also, does user think time creates any impact on Throughput?

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html):

> Throughput is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server.

> The formula is: `Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time).`

So basically throughput is the number of requests which JMeter was able to within test duration time frame. If you introduce artificial delay of 3 seconds - it will make the overall throughput lower

Other (and the main factor) is your application response time because JMeter waits for previous request to finish before executing new one so there could be 2 options:

1. The amount of threads in your Thread Groups is not sufficient to create the desired throughput. If this is the case - just add more threads (virtual users) in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)(s)
2. The amount of threads in your Thread Groups is too high and you're getting higher throughput that you expect. If this is the case you can pause JMeter even more by adding [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) and specifying the desired number of the requests per minute you want to have. If you need 6.6 requests per second it will mean 396 requests per minute

Also remember that JMeter itself must be able to send requests fast enough so make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As you mentioned that "If you introduce artificial delay of 3 seconds - it will make the overall throughput lower". In that case should we not add the user think time? Am I doing something wrong here, please guide

Comment: You should be adding realistic think times, only this way you can tell for sure how many "users" does your application support.

Comment: Should I remove the user think time if I am using the Constant Throughput Timer? I am planning to add Constant Throughput Timer at Test plan level for all 5 Thread Groups. Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to consider using the Arrivals Thread Group. This TG will allow you to configure the desire average throughput (ATP); the TG will instantiate the required threads needed to achieve the ATP goal.

As for the Think Time (TT), it should be a business requirement that emulates the pauses that users take when using the application in the real world.